# CSS Menu Not Opening in IE7

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Menu is working in all browsers but not IE7. It's not opening up.

http://goo.gl/oGR2O

Comment: I can't be bothered to dig through your source code to find the answer. Try posting only the relevant HTML, CSS, JavaScript that your are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to fix it.

```
#middle {
  *position: inherit !important;
}
```

Although it looks like you'll need to adjust the widths on the subnav items.